# PDF to XML transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt

Can we convert PDF file to XML using XSLT Transformation?

Thanks

Comment: By writing a parser of PDF file on XSLT. Do not try.

Comment: So, it's possible to do that, thanks alot :)

Comment: It's possible but not directly, so not how you think, no.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  XSL is used to convert an XML document to another form of XML (or as pointed out some other) document.  You'll need to convert it to xml first with something like this:

http://www.pdf2text.com/

Comment: Yes. Actually the output form can be any text format, but the point is the same: XSLT is not designed to be able to transform *from* PDF. It's designed to transform from XML. XSLT 2.0 can take text as input, but even that is not its strength.

Comment: The question is:
Which Transformation can NOT be done "by using XSL":

(XML to PDF)
(PDF to XML)
(XSL to XML)
(XML to HTML)
(All the above transformation can be done.)

Comment: No pdf to xml can't natively be done by only using xsl.  You need to have something interpret it first and convert it into something xsl can read.

Answer (score 0):

PDF is a binary format which would be difficult to handle in XSLT. 
Try using something like PDFBox http://pdfbox.apache.org/ to convert
PDF to text and then convert the text to XML.